# Using databases with Java on Mac

Tags: java, database, macos, ms-access, jdbc

I need to create a simple Java application that connects to a local database file, and will run on a mac.

I've figured that JDBC is a good option, but what file format/drivers should I use?
Is .MDB files a possibility?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use any database engine which provides a JDBC driver. Choices are aplenty.

Answer (score 2):

For a small DB I would suggest using a DB written in Java. The DB's below or all
< 2mb. Keeping it in java means it is easy to transfer to Windows / Linux if need be.

Possible DB's include:

[H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)  -   H2 has a mixed mode where the first time the DB is opened it is op
        Advantages:

- Mixed Mode
- Only a couple of Files
- has built-in SQL

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) - Version HSQLDB 1.80 is the smallest jar of the three (by a big margin)
     The 2.* jars are similar in size to H2
     Advantages:

- Small size (Version 1.80)
- Only a couple of Files

[Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

All three offer Server and Embedded mode, H2 has mixed mode as well. All three are open source.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Derby embedded in your application. This keeps it simple while still using standard JDBC.

H

Answer (score 0):

> Is .MDB files a possibility?

It could be, via a library like [UCanAccess](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/). However, using an Access database (.mdb or .accdb) would only be advisable if there was some other compelling reason to do so, e.g., to take a copy of the database file and use it with some other application that requires an Access database.

Otherwise, one of the suggestions from the other answers would probably be a better choice.